# Do $X(X'X)^{-1}(X'X)^{-1}X'$ and $(X'X)^{-1}$ have the same non-zero eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X$ be a matrix with full column rank. I want to show that $X(X'X)^{-1}(X'X)^{-1}X$ and $(X'X)^{-1}$ have the same non-zero eigenvalues. I have checked it in matlab and Stata and the result holds true for all the examples, but I cannot prove this formally.

Please help.

Comment: Hi @Royfan. $\color{blue}{\large{\text{Welcome to Math.SE!}}}$ You might like to know that we use [Mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) here (e.g. `$\theta$` for $\theta$).

Answer (score 3):

There is this really clever trick, I think due to von Neumann, that shows for $\lambda \ne 0$ that $\lambda I - AB$ is invertible if and only if $\lambda I - BA$ is invertible.

Suppose $U$ is an inverse of $\lambda I - AB$.  Then $\lambda^{-1}(1 + BUA)$ is an inverse for $\lambda I - BA$.  Try multiplying it out.  It really works.

Now set $A = X(X'X)^{-1}(X'X)^{-1}$ and $B = X'$.